# InvalidDataException "Could not determine container type" when using Song.FromUri to load mp3 in Monogame

Tags: c#, mp3, monogame

I am writing a jukebox application and am trying to use the built in MediaPlayer for playback.  When trying to create a Song for playback using Song.FromUri I get an InvalidDataException "Could not determine container type"

Song s = Song.FromUri(@"D:\Temp.mp3", new Uri(@"D:\Temp.mp3"));

The mp3 has ID3V1 and ID3V2 tags and is VBR (avg 198kbps) but I have tried many others with no difference.  I eliminated spaces in my filepath and have already tried removing all tags in the file.  I have also tried using every UriKind option.  Currently I am testing on Windows 10, but this will also need to run on Linux.

The mp3 will load and play via the Content Pipeline tool so I don't think there is any issue with the file itself.

I am out of ideas.  Why is this not working?  Should I use a different library for this?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem it does not seem to work with mp3 files. A solution is to download ffmpeg and convert all files to the ogg format like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 4 output.ogg
```

Comment: As a jukebox the software needs to be flexible with file formats.  A jukebox that can't play mp3s isn't very useful.  I used the NAudio library to accomplish what I was trying to do, but I am leaving this question up as it would still be of value to figure out how to do this without using a 3rd party library.